# What's the difference between "noch" and "immer noch?"

Tags: difference, expression, modal-particle

From what I got, the sentence *Sie isst immer noch* is translated to *She's still eating*.

I get what each word in the sentence translates to:

```
Sie   ->  She
isst  ->  eats/is eating
immer ->  always
noch  ->  still
```

So what exactly is *immer*'s role in the sentence there? Wouldn't *Sie isst noch* mean the same thing?

How does the expression *immer noch* differ from *noch*?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Sie isst immer noch.

Both **immer** and **noch** are used as modal particles in this sentence. I introduce the modal particle *gerade* to show the difference.

> Sie isst. → *She eats.*
>
> Sie isst gerade. → *She is eating.*
>
> Sie isst noch. → *She is still eating. (She's not ready to deal with you.)*
>
> Sie isst immer noch. → *She is still eating. (Same as it was when you looked/asked last time.)*

You may see **immer noch** as a modal particle of its own. It changes the mood to *impatient*.

> Steht ihr im Stau? → *Are you stuck in a traffic jam? (curious)*
>
> Steht ihr noch im Stau? → *Are you still stuck in a traffic jam? (commiserate)*
>
> Steht ihr immer noch im Stau? → *Are you still stuck in a traffic jam? (impatient)*

Answer (score 10):

"noch" means that the eating is ongoing, but focuses on the fact that she'll be stopping at some future point in time.

"immer noch" means that the eating is ongoing *and has done so for a long time*.

Compare:

> Das neue System ist *noch* nicht hochgefahren. (Presumably it will soon be.)
>
> Das alte System ist *immer noch* nicht ersetzt. ("We've been waiting for years! What's taking them so long??")